# UseSpaStaticFiles() in asp.net core 3 looking inside embedded resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a basic systray app that records business notes. I'm creating an asp.net core SPA in another assembly to read those notes and display it inside a browser.
I added the "frontend" web assembly as a dependency of the systray app but to use correctly the spa site I need to have the static files folder inside my app folder. I want to embed all static files inside the .net core web dll and instruct the engine to read files from there.

What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed .csproj file adding a new property

```
<GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
```

then I have added

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="clientapp/dist/**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and with the nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded I have completed the changes.